# How can I find images inside a specific class?

Tags: python, selenium

I have been trying to use `Selenium` to do a webscraping.

I need to download two lists of information: name and picture.

I used this code to download the list of names:

```py
### click on right div
browser.find_element("xpath","/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div").click()

### colect names
nomes_ls_contatos = browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "zoWT4")
len(nomes_ls_contatos) # 21
nomes_ls_contatos[1].text
```

To download the pictures, I tried:

```py
### collect pictures
fotos_ls_contatos = browser.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "img")
len(fotos_ls_contatos) # 24
print(fotos_ls_contatos[1].get_attribute("src"))
```

But in this way, it's downloading more three pictures which I don't need.

I found out the right pictures is inside a class `_3GlyB`. And tried:

```py
fotos_ls_contatos = browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "_3GlyB")
len(fotos_ls_contatos) #  20
fotos_ls_contatos[1].text
```

But it returns an empty string.

So, how can I can I do it?

Something like `browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "_3GlyB").find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "img")`

PS:
With R, this worked:

```r
# collect names
nome_remetente <- lista_mensagens[[1]] |>
   rvest::read_html() |>
   rvest::html_elements("._3vPI2") |>
   rvest::html_elements(".zoWT4") |>
   rvest::html_element("span") |>
   rvest::html_text() |>
   as.data.frame() |>
   dplyr::rename(nome = 1) |>
   dplyr::filter(!is.na(nome))


# collect pictures
imagem_remetente <- lista_mensagens[[1]] |>
   rvest::read_html() |>
   rvest::html_elements("._1Oe6M") |>
   rvest::html_elements("._2EU3r") |>
   rvest::html_elements("._3GlyB") |>
   rvest::html_elements("img") |>
   rvest::html_attr("src") |>
   as.data.frame() |>
   dplyr::rename(imagem = 1)
```

Comment: If you are unable provide the url being scraped, providing the relevant HTML code extract might help us to debug this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after I while I did:

```py
img_ls_contatos = browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, '_3GlyB')

img_ls_contatos[0].find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "img")[0].get_attribute("src")
```

This is not a beautiful way, but solved.